# Sending Information Through Twilio Using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, twilio

I have a Rails 3.2.18 app where I want to ship details of a call (includes name, age, and other information) to a recipient's phone that is already a field in the database.

So for instance a call has a unit assigned, and each unit has a medic (employee) assigned.  In the medic model there's a phone field 281-444-555 (example number).  What I want to be able to do in the calls controller is to send a SMS on create and update with the details of that call so it arrives on their phone as SMS.

I'm currently doing notifications to phones by using Email to SMS gateway 2813334444@vtext.com (example) using ActionMailer and it works "ok".  But I really want to leverage Twilio.

Here's how I'm doing the mailer action to notify the medics of calls on create/update

calls_controller

```
def create
    parse_times!
    @call = Call.new(params[:call])
    @call.dispatched_by = current_user.username

     if @call.save
      @call.send_mail(:new_call)
        redirect_to calls_path, notice: "Call #{@call.incident_number} was successfully created.".html_safe
      else
        render :new
     end
  end

def update
    parse_times!
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update_attributes(params[:call])
        unless @call.call_status == "close"
         @call.send_mail(:update_call)
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: "Call #{@call.incident_number} was successfully updated.".html_safe }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

call_mailer

```
def new_call(medic, call)
    @call = call
    @medic = medic

    mail to: [@medic.medic_sms, @medic.medic_email], :cc => "noreply@company.com", subject: "New Call: #{@call.incident_number}"
  end

  def update_call(medic, call)
    @call = call
    @medic = medic

    mail to: [@medic.medic_sms, @medic.medic_email], subject: "Updated Call: #{@call.incident_number}"
  end
```

call model (mailer method)

```
def send_mail(mail_type)
    units.each do |unit|
      CallMailer.send(mail_type, unit.incharge,  self).deliver
      CallMailer.send(mail_type, unit.attendant, self).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

This is working just fine for mailing the phones and emails of the medics, but I would like to add something similar using Twilio where I can ship the call details to them via SMS in the create and update action.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.  I have a Twilio account already and would like to put it to good use.

**Update 08/03/14**

I think I figured this out and got it working in a basic fashion.  But I'd like to see if there's someway to cleanly pass @call object data into the :body => section.  Right now I'm having to iterate over the specific fields I want to send (which are about 10 different fields).  It would be nice if I could create a partial or template and pass it to :body => similar to how ActionMailer works.  Any thoughts?

**calls_controller.rb (working)**

```
def update
    parse_times!
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update_attributes(params[:call])
        unless @call.call_status == "close"
          unless  @call.unit_ids.empty?
          send_sms
        end

        @call.send_mail(:update_call)

        end
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: "Call #{@call.incident_number} was successfully updated.".html_safe }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
  def send_sms
    account_sid = 'AC5CCCCC'
    auth_token = 'ATTTTT'
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
    @client.account.messages.create(
       :from => '2814084444',
       :to => @call.units.first.incharge.medic_phone,
       :body => "incident_number #{@call.incident_number} patient name #{@call.patient_name}"
      )
    @client.account.messages.create(
      :from => '2814084444',
       :to => @call.units.first.attendant.medic_phone,
       :body => "incident_number #{@call.incident_number} patient name #{@call.patient_name}"
      )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have this figured out now.  I needed to do string interpolation in the :body element for Twilio to send the information out.  Here is my final code and it's working and updated with a conditional to only fire Twilio if certain conditions are met.

calls_controller.rb

```
def update
    parse_times!
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update_attributes(params[:call])
        if !(@call.call_status == "close") && !(@call.unit_ids.empty?)
          send_update_sms
          @call.send_mail(:update_call)
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: "Call #{@call.incident_number} was successfully updated.".html_safe }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def send_update_sms
    account_sid = 'AC5CCCC'
    auth_token = 'ATTTT'
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
    @client.account.messages.create(
       :from => '28140844444',
       :to => @call.units.first.incharge.medic_phone,
       :body => "Updated: #{@call.incident_number}/#{@call.units.map(&:unit_name).join(", ")}/#{@call.patient_name}/#{@call.patient_age}/#{@call.patient_sex.try(:sex)}/#{@call.nature.try(:determinant)}/#{@call.special_equipments.map(&:name).join(", ")}/#{@call.traffic_type}/#{transfer_from_address}/#{transfer_to_address} CHECK EMAIL FOR FULL CALL INFO"
      )
    @client.account.messages.create(
      :from => '2814084444',
       :to => @call.units.first.attendant.medic_phone,
       :body => "Updated: #{@call.incident_number}/#{@call.units.map(&:unit_name).join(", ")}/#{@call.patient_name}/#{@call.patient_age}/#{@call.patient_sex.try(:sex)}/#{@call.nature.try(:determinant)}/#{@call.special_equipments.map(&:name).join(", ")}/#{@call.traffic_type}/#{transfer_from_address}/#{transfer_to_address} CHECK EMAIL FOR FULL CALL INFO"
      )
  end

 def transfer_from_address
    if @call.transferred_from.nil?
      @call.transfer_from_other
    else
      @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) + ' ' + @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address)
    end
  end

  def transfer_to_address
    if @call.transferred_to.nil?
      @call.transfer_to_other
    else
      @call.transferred_to.try(:facility_name) + ' ' + @call.transferred_to.try(:facility_address)
    end
  end
```